# solving the PDE of a beam under a moving load using Laplace transform

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform

> Solve this PDE using Laplace transform :
>
> $$ EI {\partial^4 y(x,t)\over\partial x^4}+\mu {\partial^2y(x,t)\over\partial t^2}= F(x,t) $$
>   $$F(x,t)= P\delta(x-u) / \int_{-\infty}^\infty\delta(x-x_0)f(x)dx = f(x_0)$$$ \delta $ is the dirac function , P is the amplitude of the applied load and $u=u(t)$ **the position of the load**
>
> initial conditions :
>
> For $x=0 , l$ :
>
> $${\partial^3 y(x,t)\over\partial x^3}=k_ly(x,t)$$ ,
>
> $${\partial^2 y(x,t)\over\partial x^2}=k_t{\partial y(x,t)\over\partial x}$$ ,
>
> $$y(x,t)= {\partial y(x,t)\over\partial t}=0$$
>
> $l$ is the beam length and $k_t$ and $k_l$ are constants

i already solved it using green functions and i wondered if there is a way to solve it using Laplace transform (because i did it when the equation = 0) ,

an attempt :

> we take : $ y(x,t) = y(x).z(t) / z(t)= z_1sin(\omega t) + z_2sin(\omega t) $
>
> $EIy^{(4)}(x) - \mu \omega^2y(x)= {F(x,t)\over z(t)} $
>
> $EI\mathcal L(y^{(4)}(x)) - \mu \omega^2\mathcal L(y(x))= \mathcal L({F(x,t)\over z(t)}) $
>
> $$\mathcal L({F(x,t)\over z(t)})=P{e^{-su}\over z(u)} : (1)$$
>
> if $(1)$ is true then the whole problem is based on the calculation of : $$\mathcal L^{-1}({e^{-su}\over s^4-\lambda^4})$$

any **hint** ? is it even possible ?

> the [paper](http://www.scientiairanica.com/PDF/Articles/00001042/mehri.pdf) .

Comment: What are the boundary conditions on $x$?  Any initial conditions?  You should also say more about $F$ unless all you want is some generalities rather than a useful example.

Comment: sorry for the mistake i found the formulation of $F(x,t)$ !

Answer (score 1):

If I am not too rusty you can use partial fraction decomposition such as
$$e^{-su}\bigg(\frac 1{s^4-\lambda^4}\bigg)=e^{-su}\bigg(-\frac 1{2\lambda^3} \frac \lambda{s^2+\lambda^2}+\frac 1{4\lambda^3}\frac 1{x-\lambda}-\frac 1{4\lambda^3}\frac 1{x+\lambda}\bigg)$$
$$\mathcal L^{-1}\Bigg(e^{-su}\bigg(-\frac 1{2\lambda^3} \frac \lambda{s^2+\lambda^2}+\frac 1{4\lambda^3}\frac 1{x-\lambda}-\frac 1{4\lambda^3}\frac 1{x+\lambda}\bigg)\Bigg)$$
Without the dirac function the inverse Laplace is 
$$\Rightarrow -\frac 1{2\lambda^3} \sin(\lambda t)+\frac 1{4\lambda^3}e^{\lambda t}-\frac 1{4\lambda^3}e^{-\lambda t}$$
and the final version
$$\Rightarrow k_u(t)\bigg(-\frac 1{2\lambda^3} \sin(\lambda t-\lambda u)+\frac 1{4\lambda^3}e^{\lambda t-\lambda u}-\frac 1{4\lambda^3}e^{-\lambda t+\lambda u}\bigg)$$
where 
$$k_u(t\lt u)=0\text{ and }k_u(t\gt u)=1$$

Please check for typos

Comment: looks fine to me but this will just lead to nothing with $g(t)$ around .. thank you for your effort anyway